# Не работает taglib в jsp страницах

Tags: java, jsp

Добрый вечер! Использую java 1.4, Tomcat 4.1.40, не работает taglib в jsp страницах

```
jstl-1.1.0.jar
taglibs-standard-compat-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-compat-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
standard.jar
```

но все безуспешно, страница загружается пустая, в структуре страницы только

```
<html>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

если в jsp странице отключить импорты

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

то загружается мой html, но следовательно без того, что должно прийти из бекенда
Первоначально делалось для Tomcat9 и Java8 там все работало.

Answer (score 1):

JSTL 1.2 требует Java не ниже 5.0 и JSP 2.1, а как следствие Tomcat не ниже 6.0.

Comment: JSTL 1.1 используется. Ставил standart-1.0 и все равно тоже самое

Comment: Для 1.1 нужен JSP 2.0, который поддерживается с Tomcat 5.5.

Comment: У меня условие от заказчика, что должен быть Tomcat 4.1.40. На данном томкате невозможно реализовать taglibs?

Comment: Тогда придётся либо спуститься до JSTL 1.0, либо обойтись вообще без JSTL.

Comment: Спасибо, но JSTL 1.0 не помог